# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 125: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, anaconda, spyder

I am reading in a file with 50000 rows and values:

> 2.711569 2.295490 4.141002

...

And numpy.loadtxt does a good job reading them and doing some calculations. Once i call my function :

```
c = setupc(2,n) # setups of cov matrix
```

with  n = 499999

it leads me to the dispatcher:

```
def _compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws):
    """
    For internal use.  Compile a specialized version of the function
    for the given *args* and *kws*, and return the resulting callable.
    """
    assert not kws

def error_rewrite(e, issue_type):
    """
    Rewrite and raise Exception `e` with help supplied based on the
    specified issue_type.
    """
    if config.SHOW_HELP:
        help_msg = errors.error_extras[issue_type]
        e.patch_message('\n'.join((str(e).rstrip(), help_msg)))
    if config.FULL_TRACEBACKS:
        raise e
    else:
        reraise(type(e), e, None)

argtypes = []
for a in args:
    if isinstance(a, OmittedArg):
        argtypes.append(types.Omitted(a.value))
    else:
        argtypes.append(self.typeof_pyval(a))
try:
    return self.compile(tuple(argtypes))
```

and gives the error:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 11, in <module>
    start.main()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 318, in main
    kernel.start()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 583, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 153, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 538, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1782, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 100, in _run
    self._loop.call_exception_handler(context)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1647, in call_exception_handler
    exc_info=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1407, in error
    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1514, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1524, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1594, in callHandlers
    lastResort.handle(record)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 894, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1033, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 947, in handleError
    traceback.print_exception(t, v, tb, None, sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\traceback.py", line 104, in print_exception
    type(value), value, tb, limit=limit).format(chain=chain):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\traceback.py", line 521, in __init__
    self._load_lines()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\traceback.py", line 533, in _load_lines
    self.__context__._load_lines()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\traceback.py", line 533, in _load_lines
    self.__context__._load_lines()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\traceback.py", line 533, in _load_lines
    self.__context__._load_lines()
  [Previous line repeated 14 more times]
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\traceback.py", line 531, in _load_lines
    frame.line
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\traceback.py", line 285, in line
    self._line = linecache.getline(self.filename, self.lineno).strip()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 16, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 137, in updatecache
    lines = fp.readlines()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 125: invalid continuation byte
```

I hope somebody can help me

EDIT:
Function setupc:

```
def setupc(m,n):
    c = np.zeros((m,m))

    for i in range(1,m+1):
        for j in range(1,m+1):

            # Heaviside
            if (i + j - n - 2 >= 0):
                heav = 1.0
            else:
                heav = 0.0

            c[i-1,j-1] = (
                2.*min(i,j) * (1.+3.*i*j - min(i,j)**2) / (n - min(i,j) +1) 
                + (min(i,j)**2 - min(i,j)**4) / ((n-i+1.)*(n-j+1.))
                + heav * ((n+1.-i-j)**4 - (n+1.-i-j)**2) / ((n-i+1.)*(n-j+1.))
                )
    return c
```

Comment: It looks like it is trying to print the traceback of an exception, but fails to read your source code, because the source file is not valid utf-8. Try running it in with a debugger and catching the `filename` in `updatecache(filename, module_globals)`. BTW, the debugger might also help you find the original error which lead to this one.

Comment: I did the debugging and it leads to that error at the place when the function "setupc" is called.

Comment: And what is `setupc`?

Comment: Just a function  that does some calculations nothing else

Comment: Well, that is the function with the error, right? And you posted all other functions, but not that one :/

Comment: When i debugg at exactly that function it leads me to the dispatcher and returns the error when executing ... return self.compile(tuple(argtypes))

Comment: *i have added that function too

Comment: Well, that code does not break with `setupc(2, 499999)`

Comment: So u think it is because of the file ? The file contains only numbers like shown